# Who is the manufacturer of this shower faucet brand?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

Does anyone know who is the manufacturer of this brand?
I need it in order to buy the appropriate diverter.

[image: Diverter]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extracted the image of the logo from the picture and edited a bit to get this.

[image]

Google search of the image revealed this.

[image]

Which led to this.

http://www.jb-products.com/

Comment: Thank you SO much. I really appreciate it!!